# How to fix Decodable error saying keynotfound?

Tags: swift, decodable

I'm trying to use decodable at its most basic level, to learn how to do it. I tried to set up decodable for some very simple JSON parsing and keep getting an error that I do not understand how to rectify:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "firstName", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"firstName\", intValue: nil) (\"firstName\").", underlyingError: nil)): file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang_Fall2018/swiftlang_Fall2018-1000.11.42/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 184

This is my code, which I've put into Playgrounds:

```
import UIKit

struct Customer : Decodable {
    var firstName :String
    var lastName :String
    var age :Int
}

let json = """
{
"firstname" : "John",
"lastName" : "Doe",
"age" : 34
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

let customer = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Customer.self, from: json)
print(customer)
```

When I print (at the bottom of the code) I expect to be seeing:

```
Customer(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 34).
```

But instead all I'm getting is the error above. Can you please explain to me what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: I think it's just a typo in your JSON string. You have `"firstname"` and the decoder expects `"firstName"`.

Comment: Case sensitivity matters: `firstName` vs. `firstname`

Comment: That is 100% correct and fixed the problem. Thank you Vlad!